# TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string error

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-test, typescript

I'm back with new question.

I'm stucked with this error: TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string

Weird thing is, My code is exactly same at both linux and window WSL.

but when I copy and paste my project from linux to WSL, it occurs above error.

Of course I did everything that I found at googling but all don't works.

Why this error occurs in windows and what should I do?

below is error message

```
TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
    at Array.join (<anonymous>)
    at GlobSync._process (/mnt/c/Users/pc/Desktop/WSL/collection_book_real/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/sync.js:112:53)
    at new GlobSync (/mnt/c/Users/pc/Desktop/WSL/collection_book_real/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/sync.js:45:10)
    at Function.globSync [as sync] (/mnt/c/Users/pc/Desktop/WSL/collection_book_real/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/sync.js:23:10)
    at lookupFiles (/mnt/c/Users/pc/Desktop/WSL/collection_book_real/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/lookup-files.js:89:24)
    at /mnt/c/Users/pc/Desktop/WSL/collection_book_real/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/collect-files.js:36:39
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/mnt/c/Users/pc/Desktop/WSL/collection_book_real/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/collect-files.js:34:26)
    at singleRun (/mnt/c/Users/pc/Desktop/WSL/collection_book_real/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:120:17)
    at exports.runMocha (/mnt/c/Users/pc/Desktop/WSL/collection_book_real/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:190:10)
    at Object.exports.handler (/mnt/c/Users/pc/Desktop/WSL/collection_book_real/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:374:11)
    at /mnt/c/Users/pc/Desktop/WSL/collection_book_real/node_modules/yargs/build/index.cjs:443:71
```

Comment: Please if you can, consider moving error text to a question. You can copy the error text, type ``` then linebreak, then paste error text, then linebreak again, then ```. If you don't understand something, paste error text to question, then I will edit this so I hope you will understand how to do that.

Comment: Thank you I did it

Comment: Now the image isn't required. You can just remove it. :)

Comment: cool! it works like pull request

Answer (score 1):

Your project folder is in WSL mnt (mounted folder from host OS). This will cause all kinds of strange behaviors.

Try running in inside WSL folder not mounted one.

Comment: Thank you for a reply! I understood your suggestion, but how can I access to my project folder using WSL without mounting? Sorry for basic question but I googled it too and cannot find some solution :(

Comment: NVM above question I added my project folder into home directory. But same error still occurs :( maybe I gotta use "anchor clean" and build again

Comment: May I ask how you copy the project folder into WSL home? If you're using host OS utilities to do the copy, WSL will not have the permission to write temp files into your project folder. You should be using Linux terminal to setup the folder.

Comment: I copied with Windows GUI which is literally copied and pasted folder using my mouse.. okay I'll try it using Linux terminal thank you